# Is there a way to know if my garage door is open remotely?

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

Is there a way to know if my garage door is open remotely? Some times I find my garage door open for no reason. I have expensive bikes in the garage and I don't want to worry about them.

Maybe get a notification when it's open. I only want to open it when I am in front of the garage. The garage has no side doors. I live in a condo.

Comment: Check into Chamberlain / Liftmaster myQ products.  There are controls for [existing doors and openers](http://www.chamberlain.com/smartphone-control-products/smartphone-connectivity). They connect to an internet gateway and your smartphone becomes a door remote with visual indication. We have 4 doors on the systrm-1 with a native myQ opener and 3 retrofited.

Answer (score 2):

If you're into DIY;
you could easily create a setup with arduino, you can check if the door is open with infrared distance sensor or a magnetic switch.
Or you could just create a circuit that is closed when the door is closed and feed that information into an arduino?

http://www.robotshop.com/blog/en/arduino-5-minute-tutorials-lesson-4-ir-distance-sensor-push-button-2-3637
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13769/how-can-i-detect-if-a-garage-door-is-opened-or-closed#13771

Answer (score 0):

Unless that is built into the opener, you will have to buy or build something. What that something is will depend on your needs and how fancy you want to make it, but it's essentially the same problem as putting an alarm on that door.

Answer (score 0):

I see several solutions:

- You could install a security camera;
- Use a garage door sensor, for example [Asante Garage Door Opener](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s//ref=mw_dp_a_s?ie=UTF8&k=Asante)  which notifies you by mail, SMS or mobile app;
- or use a smart home solution, see the review by [CNET](http://www.cnet.com/news/bringing-the-garage-online-in-the-cnet-smart-home/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over-thinking this... Having some form of motion-capture still won't help if someone is planning on making a shopping trip in your garage while you're out. If your garage door is opening when you're not there, the likely reason is probably that someone else's remote is using the same frequency.

Either way, there's probably a way to program the thing to use a different one.  Guessing it's either in the manual, or a Google search could find the procedure.

Comment: The question was more about me leaving the garage door open. Not about stopping criminals.